# Fastest way to check if an image sequence string actually exists on disk

Tags: python, image, file, sequence, exists

I have a potentially big list of image sequences from nuke. The format of the string can be:

/path/to/single_file.ext

/path/to/img_seq.###[.suffix].ext

/path/to/img_seq.%0id[.suffix].ext, i being an integer value, the values between [] being optional.

The question is: given this string, that can represent a sequence or a still image, **check if at least one image on disk corresponds to that string** in the fastest way possible.

There is already some code that checks if these files exist, but it's quite slow.

First it checks if the folder exists, if not, returns False

Then it checks if the file exists with os.path.isfile, if it does, it returns True.

Then it checks if no % or # is found in the path, and if not os.path.isfile, it returns False.

All this is quite fast.

But then, it uses some internal library which is in performance a bit faster than pyseq to try to find an image sequence, and does a bit more operations depending if start_frame=end_frame or not.
But it stills take a large amount of time to analyze if something is an image sequence, specially on some sections of the network and for big image sequences.

For example, for a 2500 images sequence, the analysis takes between 1 and 3 seconds.

If I take a very naive approach, and just checks if a frame exist by replacing #### by %04d, and loop over 10000 and break if found, it takes less than .02 seconds to check for os.path.isfile(f), specially if the first frame is between 1-3000.
Of course I cannot guarantee what the start frame will be, and that approach is not perfect, but in practice many of the sequences do begin between 1-3000, and I could return True if found and fallback to the sequence approach if nothing is found (it would still be quicker for most of the cases)

I'm not sure what's the best approach is for this, I already made it multithreaded when searching for many image sequences, so it's faster than before, but I'm sure there is room for improvement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way of determining if an image is part of a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855801/whats-the-best-way-of-determining-if-an-image-is-part-of-a-sequence)

Comment: mmm no it's really not the same. Here the question is given a string that represents an image sequence or a single image, check that at least one image of this sequence exists on disk in the fastest way possible

Comment: OK, cancel that vote to close.

Comment: Showing some code and why it isn't working for you would be a big help. You also conflate the terms "string" and "path" and some distinction would be useful.

Comment: On the command line, this would be quite fast with `find .` and two different `grep`s. Why not implement the same in Python? Get a list of all files, then run a regular expression to see if any match either of your two patterns. You haven't specified what your speed requirements are and why, but this approach should be a) pretty fast and b) gives plenty of ways to cache in case you actually mean fast amortized time. FYI Python is not built for high speed, if you want faster then Python gives you ways to call other languages.

Comment: The *fastest* way would probably be to have all file names indexed in memory. I expect it would be huge overkill for your actual problem, though. Usually it's better to ask for "a faster" approach instead of "the fastest". Also, showing some actual code often helps elicit good answers or at least helpful comments.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? Which OS? How many files per directory?Have you tried replicating some typical filesystem layouts (maybe with empty file stubs) on a RAM-based filesystem to see if the bottleneck is in disk access or system call or algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not loop for candidates using `os.path.isfile()`, but use `glob.glob()` or `os.listdir()` and check the returned lists for matching your file patterns, i.e. prefer memory operations over disk accesses.

Answer (score 0):

If there are potentially so many files that you're worried about wasting memory for a dictionary that holds them all, you could just store a single key for each img_seq.###[.suffix].ext pattern, removing the sequence number as you scan the directory. Then a single lookup will suffice. The values in the dictionary could either be "dummy" booleans because the existence of the key is the only thing you care about, or counters in case you ever want to know how many files you have for a certain sequence.